# Exposing directive controller to parent controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to expose some of my directive's functionality through its controller (think a public API for this directive).

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.method1 = ...;
            this.method2 = ...;
        },
        controllerAs: 'dir',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { ... }
    }
```

Then in my parent controller or template call `dir.method1` to get stuff accomplished inside the directive. Any ideas if this is possible as of Angular 1.3?

I'd like to refrain from event passing or even function passing, I have heard this is possible although I have never seen an implementation of this.

Comment: put the functions in a service and share the service by injecting it where you need it in the app

Comment: How would you initialize the service in this case to have the functions that I want to expose? In other words, how could I link `method1` inside a service.

Comment: put object/array or whatever it is you want to maniupulate in service, and create getter and setter methods to modify it

Comment: Without being too specific, the directive's methods only do DOM manipulation. I want the controller to orchestrate the DOM changes that happen inside the directive. There are no object/arrays involved; only method calls.

Comment: orchestrate based on what...likely data params? You can watch object properties if they are exposed

Comment: The controller manages some external interactions between the user and the directive. The directive's only concern is to manipulate the DOM based on the user's interaction with the controller. Say that the user wants to draw a duck on the screen, the user selects a UI element that represents a duck, and through some kind of trigger (thing ng-click) calls a function in the controller which then propagates that intent to the directive (which manipulates the DOM to draw the duck).

Comment: Same issue here. I find it bizarre that functionality that AFAIK is intended to provide reusable components doesn't have a clean way to provide an API. Is it hard to visualize use cases for components to provide public APIs?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but your issue isn't to figure out how to get the API out. It's how to get TO it from the parent. You're creating an [isolate scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) through your use of the 'scope' option. You're also making an element-type directive, so I'm guessing you're doing something like this:

```
<my-parent>
    <my-child></my-child>
</my-parent>
```

where `<my-parent>` is the parent directive, and `<my-child>` is the directive with the API you want to expose.

The real question is what you're trying to achieve here. There is totally a way to do what you're asking. Just because the scope is isolated doesn't mean you can't get to it. You can just iterate through the parent $scope's $$childHead/etc list to find the child whose API you want to access. Anything you define in the child like this:

```
$scope.myApiFunction = function() {
};
```

will be visible here. (Things you put into 'this' will not - use the $scope storage bucket instead.)

That means if you only had ONE child you could do something like this from the parent controller:

```
$scope.$$childHead.myApiFunction();
```

Simple. Also, very crude. There are lots of problems here: what if you have many children? What if this child with its API ends up one level down? Etc. It's breaking all kinds of OO patterns and it's going to get messy, fast.

Your question is very abstract - it might be good if you updated it with an exact example. Without that, let me guess at your goal. There are two ways to do something "like this" that are encouraged within Angular:

1. Services. Whenever you say "API", think Service first. A service is a singleton (automatically) so it's tailor-made for creating APIs. And services can use the Factory pattern to return objects of a type, so THOSE are tailor made for doing things like having a manager service handle, say, a buddy list in an IM client, with API methods for creating, removing, and finding buddies.
2. Items that add "optional" functionality to their parents when they're defined. Let's say we have three possible types of tooltips: tooltips that have a hover effect, those that have a click effect, and those that are triggered by a "walkthrough" system in some order. For this kind of thing, the easy thing to do is just reverse the API, like this:

Parent Controller:

```
$scope.tooltipHandler = {
    showTooltip: function() {},
    hideTooltip: function() {}
};
```

Child Controller:

```
$scope.$parent.tooltipHandler = {
    showTooltip: function() {
        // Do some real work
    },
    hideTooltip: function() {
        // Do some real work
    },
}
```

What happens here is if there's no tooltip defined, when the parent runs its walkthrough, nothing happens. If you add the blue tooltip display module, when the parent runs its walkthrough now, it's going to show blue tooltips.

Make sense?

Comment: Actually, if I was wrapping it my child directive inside a parent directive, I would use the `require` option and be done with it. The parent of this directive is a plain old controller.

Comment: There's very little difference. A directive is just a convenient wrapper that makes it easy to bring together a template, a controller, and support components. The controller that runs *inside* a directive is identical to the controller that runs *outside* one. It doesn't matter whether you make it with `<div ng-controller="MyController"></div>` or `<my-directive></my-directive>` and define it inside there. The techniques above work in both cases in exactly the same way. What matters here is *scope*... which also works exactly the same way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here looking for a similar response. So far the best that I can figure is to do what Angular does with `ngForm`.

In the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) clearly states

> If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.

This basically makes the form controller accessible from anywhere.

If you have the following DOM

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as parentCtrl">
  <form name="parentCtrl.frmCtrl">
     <my-child-directive>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can use `require: 'ngForm'` in `my-child-directive` to get access from an inside directive. If you are in the parent controller you can access it trough the `frmCtrl` variable.

Not sure if this is best practice. In ngForm the `name` attribute works well, but I don't even know how to call such an attribute for a custom directive.

Thats why I arrived here, I wanted to know if this is "The Angular way" and what types of convetions are on the subject.

Hope it helps!